# Feeding network strategy for simultaneously supplying amplifiers

Tags: pcb

There is an amplifier board of QPA2575 the DC feeding GND is at `METAL_3_BOT` while the RF signal has ground at `METAL_2_MID`.

The DC connector is HUGE as shown below. Basically I need to simultaneously feed all 4 amplifiers.

From looking at the data sheet I have this schematic shown in the last photo.

How do I build a feeding network for such a complex connector so it will feed all 4 amplifiers?

Datasheet: https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/QPA2575

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to route the power signals on the PCB? Also, without further explanation those images aren't very helpful.